# Android> Creating phone app using custom code OR modifying source code for built-in native phone

Tags: android, arduino, telephonymanager

I am a novice Android-Java developer and am building a custom telephony application. 
From my understanding there are 2 approaches I can take.

1. Build a custom app from scratch using the SDK and TelephonyManager class
2. Or, grab the entire native app source from source.android.com and 'hack' the existing phone application.

The application MUST run in kiosk mode and also run automatically when the device is powered on, both of which I am still researching.
It will also need to communicate via the Android Open Accessory Protocol with an external arduino device (no voice data, probably just volume levels).

Can any android experts suggest which approach, 1 or 2 is going to be easiest to implement and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong than you are going to implement it using Java in that case I would suggest 3rd Option.

Option 3: Write your own wrapper on top of existing TelephonyManager and extend the feature functionality.

I am not sure how deep you are going to change the existing API but in case you are going to enhance the feature than this option seems good.

Comment: Thanks. Yes java. Would there be any advantage at all in option 2? My guess is that it would be much more difficult but perhaps expose more functionality than #1 or #3?

Comment: Yes you are true. But if you are not going to add any method which is going to talk to machine level (you have to provide the JNI code for that) than better go with option 3. As you are just adding few more functionality and feature on top of it.